# Unhandled Exception. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idComplejo' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

when I open it, I have this error:

> Unhandled Exception. 
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idComplejo' cannot be null

This is my php:

```
<?php 

require("Db.class.php");


$db = new Db();

$response = array();


 $idComplejo= $_POST['idComplejo'];
 $idUsuario= $_POST['idUsuario'];


$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO baneo(idComplejo, idUsuario)   VALUES(:idComplejo, :idUsuario)",
    array("idComplejo" => $idComplejo, "idUsuario" => $idUsuario));

if($result == 0) { 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["mensaje"] = "Error";
}

else if($result > 0){
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["mensaje"] = "Success";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Obviously, if I just open the php the variables are NULL. But I want to show this error if someone open this php:

```
 $response["success"] = 0;
 $response["mensaje"] = "Error";
```

The reason is because I want to secure my file and i don't want to show how my database looks like.

Thanks

Comment: Run a check before trying to run the insert.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how can I run a check. Could you tell me? Thanks

Comment: Check both  POST variable by isset at the starting.

Comment: <?php isset($_POST['idComplejo'] && $_POST['idUsuario']){//all code come here }

Comment: I have this error like you said  @Rishi :
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code needs some restructuring. Make sure you have values before attempting to insert as noted above

```
  <?php 

        require("Db.class.php");
        $db = new Db();
        $response = array();

        if(!empty($_POST['idComplejo']) && !empty($_POST['idUsuario'])){
              $idComplejo= $_POST['idComplejo'];
              $idUsuario= $_POST['idUsuario'];
        }else{
             $response["success"] = 0;
             $response["mensaje"] = "Error";
        }

        if(!isset($response["mensaje"])){
              //Required data is here
              $result = $db->query("INSERT INTO baneo(idComplejo, idUsuario)   VALUES(:idComplejo, :idUsuario)",array("idComplejo" => $idComplejo, "idUsuario" => $idUsuario));
       }


      if($result) { 
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["mensaje"] = "Success";
      }

      echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Comment: No problem sir. Happy to help.